# Debian, nonroot, cron, bash script and rebooting at specific time

Tags: linux, bash, cron, non-root-user, reboot

As nonroot user, how can I schedule a reboot every day at 4:30am?

30 04 * * * /home/user/scripts/reboot.sh

As a nonroot normal user, I'm sure the system won't allow me to use the reboot command.

What settings do I need to change in Debian order to make this scheduled reboot work? (without asking for sudo password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `cron` entry in `/etc/cron.d` or `/etc/crontab` for it to be run as root. If you put it in a new file under `/etc/cron.d`, that format should work (`/etc/crontab` uses a slightly different format).